# Xampp vhosts do not work

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have trouble with xampp. Having installed it, my virtual hosts do not want to work at all.
When i am trying to access `http://localhost/` - works good. But if i type something else, like `http://laravel.dev` it gives me an error.

**hosts**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.dev
```

**Virtual Hosts**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80


#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
       ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/sites/laravel.dev/www"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I first started to use XAMPP. It was really hard to find answer online, so I have started to experiment myself. The solution that worked for me was to **clear the browser cache. :)** Yes that was simple as this ...

For those who do not know:

> ***hosts*** file can be found in ***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*** directory and
>
> ***httpd-vhost.conf*** can be found in ***C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra*** directory

Ps. here you go - my working configuration. (Don't forget to clear your browser cache after you have made the changes to those files and restart your Apache server in your xampp panel) *Note that to edit hosts file you have to run the editing program such as Notepad++ as administrator. If you don't do it your editing program will not be able make any changes to that file.**

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1  symfony.dev
127.0.0.1  symfony
```

**httpd-vhost.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@symfony.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@symfony.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/_DoNotTouch_Symfony2/path/web"
    ServerName symfony.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

One more little thing... When you run your virtual server in the browser make sure that you will use http:// before the server name (at last at the first time you will call it). So run:

> http://symfony.dev

after that you will be able to use only

> symfony.dev

(That how it works in a Google Chrome browser anyway)

Thumbs up if I have helped to solve your issue ;-).

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what kind of Error do you see?

There could be a problem if you don't specify a correct  along your Vhost. Try to adapt your second vhosts to something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/sites/laravel.dev/www"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp2/sites/laravel.dev/www">
        DirectoryIndex index.php   ## Edit this to your needs, e.g. index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I encountered some problems using absolute paths, try to use relative paths (e.g. "sites/laravel.dev/www") and check if that makes a difference.